# Why svn asks my password twice?

Tags: svn

Occasionally, when I update with svn, it asks the password for the ssh at the beginning, then updates a bunch of files, then asks it stops and asks it again to continue. What exactly is the reason for this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Version control with subversion](http://books.google.be/books?id=b3TsOSvU5TUC&lpg=PA204&ots=zTFC7-8cvB&dq=When%20using%20svn%2bssh://%20URLs%20to%20access%20a%20repository,%20remember%20that%20it%27s%20the%20ssh%20program%20prompting%20for%20authentication,%20and%20not%20the%20svn%20client%20program.%20Th&hl=nl&pg=PA204#v=onepage&q=When%20using%20svn%20ssh://%20URLs%20to%20access%20a%20repository,%20remember%20that%20it%27s%20the%20ssh%20program%20prompting%20for%20authentication,%20and%20not%20the%20svn%20client%20program.%20Th&f=false):

> When using svn+ssh:// URLs to access a repository, remember that it's the ssh program prompting for authentication, and not the svn client program. That means there's no automatic password-caching going on (see the section called "Client Credentials Caching"). The Subversion client often makes multiple connections to the repository, though users don't normally notice this due to the password caching feature. When using svn+ssh:// URLs, however, users may be annoyed by ssh repeatedly asking for a password for every outbound connection. The solution is to use a separate SSH password-caching tool such as ssh-agent on a Unix-like system, or pageant on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your connection to SVN server was reset and your client automatically re-established it which caused asking for your password? If SVN server is implemented as PHP module, there maybe some time limit for server to answer client's requests. What file is being updated when you encounter this problem? Maybe connection is reset when you try to update a big file?

Comment: "If SVN server is implemented as PHP module" - is that common? I've never seen that

Comment: I meant SVN module for Apache HTTP server. We have PHP-coded web-site and SVN server on the same machine. Both use the same Apache to deliver content via HTTP. Don't actually know whether SVN is implemented as Apache module or as PHP-addon.